# MySQL: Arithmetic Operator Multiplication

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate from a field within  the table. I am trying to do some date range stuff. Currently I have a table with the a field named `interval` which stores minutes. I would like to convert this field to seconds. I know I can probably store the data as seconds but out of curiosity how come this is not working for me?

```
SELECT table.`interval`*60 AS interval_seconds FROM table;
```

If the fields contained 60 I was expecting 3600 to output. But instead I get 60. If I change the value to 5 instead of 300 I get 360. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, The problem is the field type is ENUM. So it was multiplying by the index.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you found that. I used to pepper my tables with enum's, a long time ago. But issues similar to what you just faced brought me to dislike them very much. For a little more details on the dirty aspects of enums,  [see this post](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/).

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. Looks like I will stop using enums for sure.